Convert string to a palindrome
Given string s, we can add characters at beginning. Task is to turn s into a palindrome while performing as few operations as possible.
1<=|s|<=10^5
def make_palindrome(s):
    if s == s[::-1]:
        return s  # If the string is already a palindrome, return it
        
    
    for i in range(len(s),0, -1):
        if s[:i] == s[:i][::-1]:
            return s[i:][::-1] + s

Here's my code it passes most cases, but for some I get Time limit exceeded, exceeds 2 seconds. Can you help to optimize?
Ex. abcd -> dcbabcd aabc -> cbaabc kayak -> kayak

return s+s[::-1] super fast, single operation

@Daviid We should add characters only from beginning
Ex.
abcd -> dcbabcd
aabc -> cbaabc
kayak -> kayak

Sorry, that was a joke answer, however I don't think I quite understand the requirements. You can only add characters FROM the beginning or AT the beginning? Can you update your question with examples, preferably those that pass and those that time out.

@Daviid, Yes my mistake, AT the beginning, also added examples.

And which ones time out?

It's possible that adding AT beginning or ending can yield different answers, e.g. aabbbbbbbb, your solution would be bbbbbbbbaabbbbbbbb, while from the other side it would be aabbbbbbbbaa

@Daviid Tests are hidden

@Elerium115 Adding few characters

We must trade the convenience of slices for speed. Each slice for creating a substring (possibly reversed) means to create a new object (possibly a large one). Here is an old-fashioned char-by-char comparison of characters at some index. It brings back memories of while (*p1++ == *--p2) ; ... nevermind.
def is_palindrom(word: str, n: int) -> bool:
    """Is word[:n] a palidrom?"""
    b = 0
    while b < n:
        n -= 1
        if word[b] != word[n]:
            return False
        b += 1
    return True

def make_palindrom(word: str) -> str:
    n = len(word)
    while not is_palindrom(word, n):
        n -= 1
    return word[:n-1:-1] + word


Thanks, this solution passed all tests.
